# Basic LaTeX questions

Tags: latex

Two (hopefully quick) questions about LaTeX:

1. How do you number select functions? I'm working in a `documentclass{article}`, if that matters. I want to have certain functions numbered such as

   ```
   function1  
   function2 (1)  
   function3  
   function4 (2)
   ```
2. How do you make a sign to evaluate an integral? I know how to do brackets, but is it possible to only make one straight light to the right of the function with the bounds of integration? I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to (1).

```
\begin{eqnarray}
function1  \nonumber \\
function2            \\
function3  \nonumber \\
function4 
\end{eqnarray}
```

The answer to (2).

```
$\left. \frac 12 \right|_1^2$
```

Comment: eqnarray environments really oughtn't be used -- as noted in the AMS Short Math Guide (ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf), they "produce inconsistent spacing of the equal signs and make no attempt to prevent overprinting of the
equation body and equation number."

Your solution works great if you use an align environment instead though!

Answer (score 3):

I did what you asked in LyX and exported to LaTex:

```
\begin{document}
\L{\begin{equation}

\int_{0}^{1}x^{2}=\left.\frac{1}{3}x^{3}\right|_{0}^{1}=\frac{1}{3}\end{equation}
}

\L{\[
a=b+c\]
}

\L{\begin{equation}
1+1=2\end{equation}
}
\end{document}
```

---

**Edit:** Oh, and while you didn't ask - check out [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), since you'll definitely need to look up symbols in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to add a note to a piece of text, such that it renders something like the following:

```
The fox[1] jumped over the fence
...

[1] A fox is a clever mythical creature
```

then you can use the `\footnote{}` command, like so:

```
The fox\footnote{A fox is a clever mythical creature} jumped over the fence
```

If you wish to number an equation so you can refer to it later in your text, such that it renders something like the following:

```
    f(x,y)=3π    (1)

is numbered 1.
```

then you can use the `\equation{}` environment with a `\label`:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{f}
f(x,y)=3\pi
\end{equation}
is numbered \ref{f}.
```

Lastly, as for integration:

```
\[\int \frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}dx\]
from 0 to 1,
\[\left.\frac{sin(x)}{cos(x)}\right|_0^1\]
```

Comment: Explicitly labeling the equations is probably what I would do too -- as Wilhelm says, it allows you to refer back to them automatically, which is convenient, and works even when all of the equations are right after one another (though they are in your example, this is good to know for future reference!)